# Ubuntu 16.04 - Vagrant Box issue : ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I found an issue when i ssh to the vagrant machine in ubuntu 16.04 machine.

> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Answer (score 0):

I just halt my virtual box as mentioned below

1. vagrant halt
2. vagrant up
3. vagrant ssh

It started working for me